# Hölder continuity and uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, holder-spaces

Is uniform boundedness is related to Hölder continuity of a function?

I mean is it necessary to prove first uniform boundeness to prove the Hölder continuity of a function?

Also tell me the practical meaning of cone of influence. I know it is already being explained on  this site, but I wants to learn the practical significance of it if possible.

Comment: I answered the first part. The second part appears to be completely unrelated. It also appears to be extremely vague. Yes, cone of influence is something important for hyperbolic PDE. What do you want to know about?  This should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

A Hölder continuous function may be unbounded. For example, for any $\alpha\in (0,1]$ the function $f(x)=|x|^{\alpha}$ is   unbounded   on $\mathbb R$; yet it is Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$.

However, if the domain of a Hölder continuous  function is a bounded subset of $\mathbb R$ (or of $\mathbb R^n$), then the function is also bounded. This is true for all uniformly continuous functions, actually. Here is a proof by contradiction: suppose there is a sequence $x_n$ such that $|f(x_n)|\to \infty$. Since $x_n$ is bounded, it has a convergent subsequence $x_{n_k}$. This subsequence is Cauchy. Use uniform continuity to conclude that $f(x_{n_k})$ is also Cauchy. But every Cauchy sequence is bounded, a contradiction.